# Scraping html with rvest - getting http error 416

Tags: html, r, scrape, rvest

I am trying to scrape the HTML of this page using R (package rvest), but am getting "client error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable"

After a long search, I can't seem to find a solution.  It throws the error when trying to use rvest's html function, which parses an HTML page:

```
url <- "http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/onslaught/polluted-delta"
html(url)
```

I am using R version 3.2.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Install the new version from `github` using `devtools::install_github("hadley/rvest")` and it should work. `html` is now `read_html`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user227710.  `read_html` worked without erroring, but it only returned 2 lines and they make me think the website blocks scraping: `[1] <head>\n<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>\n<meta http-equiv="cache-control" cont ...
[2] <body>\n<div id="distil_ident_block">Â </div>\n</body>`

Comment: `read_html` now gives only 2 lines of output (by default).

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, just keep extracting from `url` with the now updated `read_html`:

```
> read_html(url) %>%
+   html_nodes("table") %>%
+   html_text() %>%
+   .[[1]]
[1] "\r\n                                Rarity:\r\n                                                R\r\n                                                Card Type:\r\n                                                Land \r\n                                                Description:\r\n                                                Tap, Pay 1 life, Sacrifice Polluted Delta:  Search your library for an island or swamp card   and put it into play. Then shuffle your library.\r\n\r\n                                \r\n                        "
```